# What does "O.G." stand for?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

Currently reading "Slang for the ages. It's swag. bae," by Kory Stamper from International New York Times (October 6, 2014), I came across this acronym O.G.

> "It[swag]'s generally taken to be a shortened form of the verb
>   "swagger," which was used to denote a certain insolent cockiness by
>   William Shakespeare, O.G."

Definitions of O.G. I have found so far are the following two:

1. officer of the guard.
2. original gum: the gum on the back of a stamp when it is issued to the public.

I think it is the second one (only because the first one doesn't seem fit) but what does *original gum* really mean? I am still confused.

Maybe some explanation with the context will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification on your original gum - In the world of philately (Stamp collecting), original gum means that the stamp was never attached to anything, either by licking the adhesive and sticking it to a letter, or the lick and stick "hinges" that they used for mounting stamps in an album for a period. If a stamp still has the original gum that it started with, it is potentially worth much more than a stamp that has been stuck to something.

Comment: Amongst the Hmong population, OG doesn't have a meaning, although it is typically used when speaking of the older people, such as grandparents, uncles and aunts, friends' parents etc.

Comment: To some people in my generation, "OG" would mean "Oh God!"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's slang for (and an abbreviation of) [**Original Gangster**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OG).

> 1. someone who has been around, old school gangster
>
> *Urban Dictionary*

Commonly used to refer to someone who is not a gangster, but is considered highly skilled in a particular area.

Comment: WOW to you! This is great! I love how it fits with the whole article! PERFECT! Thanks a lot! :-) I will have to wait 6 more mins. to check your answer.. argh- ;-)

Comment: @N.R.inSeoul It's polite to wait a little while to give time for people to write more complete answers, but in any case the term was popularized by *O.G. Original Gangsta*, a 1991 song and album by Ice-T, about an experienced, accomplished, and authentic rapper and street thug.

Comment: @choster - There's a system-enforced 12-minute wait before the OP can accept an answer (2 days if its their own answer) - Which should be enough. Not to mention that if someone else posts an even better answer, the OP can change the accept at any point.

Comment: And triple OG is the ultimate.  As I've never heard quadruple OG used.

Comment: "Opera Ghost" just got a lot more context.

Answer (score 0):

OG also refers to "ocean grown", in reference to marijuana. Which likely contributed to it becoming synonymous with 'original'.

Comment: That's [debatable](http://www.medicaljane.com/2013/01/05/the-legend-of-og-kush/), but with the word *swag* in the text (crappy weed), we'd be remiss if no one mentioned marijuana. Which that article fails to incorporate entirely. They're obviously not up to par on the modern slang usage of *OG* and *swag*.

Answer (score -3):

I think it means "original gangster" or "other girl"

Comment: Since the context (which he poster supplies in the body of the question) is a sentence that ends with "William Shakespeare, OG," and since the highest-voted answer already accounts for the "original gangster" part of your answer, your answer will be on point (and nonrepetitive) only if you can explain why "William Shakespeare, other girl" is a plausible option. On the other hand, if we treat the poster's header as the (broader) question to be answered, your answer might pass muster if you added an explanation of where and under what circumstances people use "OG" to mean "other girl."

Answer (score -4):

*Other Girl*.  That's what most people say, "I'm at the house w/ my og".